# Cakephp 2.X Website Looks Cached

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am trying to spin up a web application but Im having a really small problem and Im not sure how to handle it. I have did it before a long time ago but forgot (CLUTZ). When I try to access my application I see the login screen but it looks cached. I see a white page and I can see the links. The layout doesn't load for some reason. Like I said, this is a very small issue that I know someone can assist me with. If you give an answer please explain so that I can learn from it. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is CSS not loading. Doublecheck your `<link href="…" rel="stylesheet"/>` tags to ensure that they're pointing to the correct files.

Comment: Ok. I will check on it.